# teiid importer.schemaPattern property didn't work

Tags: java, mysql, xml, wildfly, teiid

I'm trying create vdb with mysql datasource use below xml:

```
<vdb name="my_vdb" version="1">
  <model name="my_vdb" visible="true">
    <property name="importer.schemaPattern" value="xxxx"/>
    <source connection-jndi-name="java:/mysql234" name="mysql234" translator-name="mysql"/>
  </model>
</vdb>
```

vdb created,but all schema in mysql datasource were loaded in vdb,How could i do to just load one schema in one model

Answer (score 0):

You should open an issue or create a stackoverflow post, but generally not both.  I'm marking https://github.com/teiid/teiid/issues/1263 as resolved and moving the comment here:

There's not much to go by here. The vdb snippet shows the correct setting. What schema are you actually getting from the source? Keep in mind that the pattern is like match string, so the meta characters % and _ can be problematic. Also the support for the schemaPattern is coming from the driver's implementation of DatabaseMetaData - what driver are you using?